# organazing my html and css code(images appers in the middle of the tab )

Tags: html, css

i am beginner in **html** and **css** and when i was trying to build this web page with it (html and css) ,the images always appears in the middle of the tab and i don't know how to organize it,

stackoverflow keep saying "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" i have nothing more to say lol , so thank you in advance:)

this my html code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  <title>HOME</title>
</head> 
<body>
  <div class="mytabs">
    <input type="radio" id="tabfree" name="mytabs" checked="checked">
    <label for="tabfree">Free</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <h2>Free</h2>
      <p>Mathematics (from Greek: μάθημα, máthēma, 'knowledge, study, learning') includes the study of such topics as quantity (number theory),[1] structure (algebra),[2] space (geometry),[1] and change (mathematical analysis).[3][4][5] It has no generally accepted definition.[6][7]

Mathematicians seek and use patterns[8][9] to formulate new conjectures; they resolve the truth or falsity of such b
h
.</p>
    </div>

    <input type="radio" id="tabsilver" name="mytabs">
    <label for="tabsilver">Ser</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <h2>Sr</h2>
      <p>jctivity from as far back as written records exist. The research required to solve mathematical problems can take years or even centuries of sustained inquiry.

Rigorous arguments first appeared in Greek mathematics, most notably in Euclid's Elements.[10] Since the pioneering work of Giuseppe Peano (1858–1932), David Hilbert (1862–1943), and others on axiomatic systems in the late 19th century, it has beco.</p>
    </div>

    <input type="radio" id="tabgold" name="mytabs">
    <label for="tabgold">Gd</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <h2>Gd</h2>
      <p>slow pace until the Renaissance, when mathematical innovations interacting with new scientific discoveries led to a rapid increase in the rate of mathematical discovery that has continued to the present day.[11]l
</p>
    </div>
<!--
  IMAGES
-->
<div class='all-image'>
  <div class='single-pic'>
    <img src='images/brid2.jpg' >
    <div class="image-text">
      <h1>bride</h1>
      <p>hapyy bride happy life</p>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='all-image'>
  <div class='single-pic'>
    <img src='images/brid1.jpg' >
    <div class="image-text">]
      <h1>bride</h1>
      <p>hapyy bride happy life2</p>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='all-image'>
  <div class='single-pic'>
    <img src='images/image.jpg' >
    <div class="image-text">]
      <h1>bride</h1>
      <p>hapyy bride</p>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

this is my css code:

```
/*tab*/

.mytabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 25px;
}
.mytabs input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
.mytabs label {
    padding: 25px;
    background: white;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.mytabs .tab {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff; 
    order: 1;
    display: none;
.mytabs .tab h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.mytabs input[type='radio']:checked + label + .tab {
    display: block;
}

.mytabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: #18ffff;
    border-radius: 18px; 
}
.all-image{
  text-align: center;
}
.all-image .single-pic{
  display: flex;
  padding: 24px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

thank you in advance :).

Comment: You could explain where the images belong, what you tried, what it shouldn't do. that is why only posting code saying it doesn't work like expected is not accepted

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your issue? You have the style `.all-image { text-align: center; }`, is that the problem? You say that the images always appear in the middle of the tab; where do you expect them to appear?

Comment: @Billy Brown under the tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider deleting

```css
  .mytabs .tab {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(114, 35, 35);
  order: 1;
  display: none;
  .mytabs .tab h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
```

It already looks a whole lot better.

Answer (score 0):

The **all-image** class have `text-align` set to center. Since you defined the class in the `div` element that is the parent element of your `img` tag, your image will be aligned to the center too.

To avoid your image being centered and I assume you only want your text to be aligned centered, try to set the CSS property `text-align: center` under the class **image-text**.